# Bash-scripting. Check file-status

Tags: bash, shell

I've been handed an assignment which goes as follows; 
I should write a program that checks a file and print out if one of the following happens:

1. File is created
2. file is modified
3. file is deleted

I've made a working program ( my noobish way):

```
bool=true

if [ -e "$1" ]

then

dato=$(date -r "$1" "+%s")

datony=$(date -r "$1" "+%s")
while [ "$bool" = true ]
do
echo "File exists!"
sleep $2
datony=$(date -r "$1" "+%s")
if [ "$dato" -ne "$datony" ]
then
bool=false
echo "File modified!"
fi
if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
bool=false
echo "File erased"
fi
done
fi

if [ ! -e "$1" ]
then
while [ "$bool" = true ]
do
echo "File does not exist!"
sleep $2
if [ -e "$1" ]
then
bool=false
echo "File created!"
fi
done
fi
```

The problem now is that i should make a new script that should take multiple files and check their statuses using my existing script. I need som help with how i should use my script to do that.

Comment: It depends on how you take multiple files as argument. You can read it from a file or as multiple arguments or as single argument with some delimeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using $1 for files and $2 for sleep time.

first, put sleep time in a variable

```
sleepTime=$2
```

Put all the code you already made in a function (or a program)

```
checkFile(){
    bool=true

    if [ -e "$1" ]
    then
        dato=$(date -r "$1" "+%s")
        datony=$(date -r "$1" "+%s")
        while [ "$bool" = true ]
        do
            echo "File exists!"
            sleep $2
            datony=$(date -r "$1" "+%s")
            if [ "$dato" -ne "$datony" ]
            then
                bool=false
                echo "File modified!"
            fi
            if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
                bool=false
                echo "File erased"
            fi
        done
    fi

    if [ ! -e "$1" ]
    then
        while [ "$bool" = true ]
        do
            echo "File does not exist!"
            sleep $2
            if [ -e "$1" ]
            then
                bool=false
                echo "File created!"
            fi
        done
    fi
}
```

create another function to separate the files and call the other function on background.

```
func_splitFiles(){ 
    while [ ! -z $1 ]; 
    do 
        checkFile $1 $sleepTime &
        shift; 
    done; 
}
```

In the "main" program you just call the function to split files passing $1

```
func_splitFiles $1
```

You should call the program passing files between quotes.

```
program.sh "file1 file2 file3" 1
```